# How do we apply JSON Schema Validation to message response?

Tags: json, citrus-framework

I am trying to write some sample code with Citrus Framework. Being my first attempt, I am unable to validate the JSON schema for response message.

I have added schema-repository to citrus-context.xml file but do not knnow how to use this with Java code.

**Citrus-Context File**

```
<citrus:schema-repository id="schemaRepository" type="json">
        <citrus:schemas>
            <citrus:schema id="petCreation" location="classpath:org/logica/citrus/samples/PetCreationJSONSchema.json"/>
        </citrus:schemas>
</citrus:schema-repository>
```

**Java File**

```
@CitrusTest
    public void end2endTest()
    {
        http().client(restClient).send().post("/pet").contentType("application/json").payload(new ClassPathResource("org\\logica\\citrus\\samples\\PetJSONCreation.json"));

        http().client(restClient).receive().response(HttpStatus.OK).messageType(MessageType.JSON);
    }
```

Where to apply schema validation code if working with JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Once the Json schema is available in the schema repository the validation is automatically done upon processing the incoming message in a `receive` action.

The only thing you need to do is to provide the schema name on that `receive` that you would like to use for the validation.

```java
http().client(restClient)
      .receive()
      .response(HttpStatus.OK)
      .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
      .jsonSchema("petCreation");
```

With XML schema Citrus can auto pick the right schema from the repository by its namespace. In Json we do not have something like namespaces so you need to give the schema name explicitly.